# How to install Zxing CPP (C++) on RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, qr-code, zxing

As the title, I want to build an environment of ZXing C++ on Raspberry Pi.
According to the https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp instruction, I try to build it.
However, I face some problems, like Cmake error below.
Anyone has the experience that build a environment of ZXing C++, and compile programs successfully?
Hope you can share the steps, thanks!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must add your CMake file and also all console output.

Comment: CMake file is directly download from https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp. Console output, I add later. Thank you for your advice.